# No validator could be found for constraint

Tags: java, spring

So im trying to implement my custom validation with annotation and something is wrong. Down below I put my examples.

Error:

`javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'com.spring.mvc.demo.validation.CourseCode' validating type 'com.spring.mvc.demo.validation.CourseCode'. Check configuration for 'courseCode' at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.throwExceptionForNullValidator(ConstraintTree.java:166) at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:181) at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:111) at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:82) at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:116) at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:109) at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:552) at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:510) at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:479) at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:444) at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:394) at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:183)`

This is my `CourseCOde` annotation class:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = CourseCodeConstraintValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CourseCode {

public String value() default "LUV";

public String message() default "must start with LUV";

public Class<?>[ ]groups() default {};

public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};
}
```

And how im trying to add annotation:

```
@CourseCode
private String courseCode;
```

Comment: Mistake was `private CourseCode courseCode` to `private String courseCode`

Comment: Can you add CourseCodeConstraintValidstor code?

Comment: Did you implement `CourseCodeConstraintValidator` class implementing interface `ConstraintValidator<CourseCode, String>` ?